# Node apply regular expression to stream

Tags: node.js, regex, stream

I want to apply a regular expression to the data we get from input stream and return a stream of response.

Here is what I tried:

```
const stream = require('stream');

function processStream(is, expression) {
    // I have to write code from here
    is.on("data", (chunk) => {
        expression.test(chunk);
        // how to return the result back
    });
}
```

Code to test this program:

```
const is = stream.Readable.from(['aaa', 'aab']).setEncoding('utf-8');

const os = filterStream(is, /aaa/i);

streamToArray(os).then(consolo.log, console.error);
```

I want to know how to apply a regular expression to the data and return response.

For my task, I have to write code inside function: `function processStream(is, expression) {`   I have to return a stream with chunks that match the provided regular expression.

Comment: "For my task, I have to write…". Sounds like a homework assignment (or that you're looking for someone to do your work for you).

Answer (score 1):

Since a stream arrives in chunks, you must decide what to do if one chunk does not match the regular expression, but together with the next chunk it would match. Note that you cannot control how the stream is cut into chunks!

If you want to match the incoming stream not chunk by chunk but line by line (which you can control), and output only the matching lines, you can use [`readline.createInterface`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/readline.html#readlinecreateinterfaceoptions):

```js
class Matcher extends stream.Transform {
  constructor(expression) {
    super();
    this.is = new stream.PassThrough();
    readline.createInterface({input: this.is, crlfDelay: Infinity})
    .on("line", function(line) {
      var m = line.match(expression);
      if (m) this.push(line + "\n");
      // or: this.push(m[0]) if you only want the match, not the whole line
    }.bind(this));
  }
  _transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    this.is.write(chunk);
    callback();
  }
}
function processStream(is, expression) {
  return is.pipe(new Matcher(expression));
}
```

If you want to match chunk by chunk, it is simpler:

```js
class Matcher extends stream.Transform {
  constructor(expression) {
    super();
    this.expression = expression;
  }
  _transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    if (chunk.toString(encoding).match(this.expression))
      this.push(chunk);
    callback();
  }
}
```

But then the result then depends on how the chunks happen to be cut.

Comment: For my task, I have to write code inside function : `function processStream(is, expression) {
`  I have to return a stream with chunks matching the given regular expression.

Comment: But I am supposed to write my code inside `function processStream(is, expression)`, also for my task I need to apply the regular expression to the current chunk itself, I need not check the next coming chunks and apply on the whole data.

Comment: See my augmented answer.